# Numpy: loadtxt() with variable number of columns

Tags: numpy

I have a file of tab-separated values where the first half of the file has 3 columns and N rows and the second half has 2 columns and M rows. I need to convert such a file into two separate arrays: a 3xN and a 2xM.

Example:

```
   6.7900209022264466       -3.8259897286289504        13.563976248832137     
   1.5334543760683907        12.723711617874176        1.5148291755004299     
   2.4282763900233522        9.1305022788201136       -3.1003673775485394     
  -6.5344717544805586E-002  -12.487743380186622        2.6928902187606480     
   8.9067951331740804        13.403331728374390      -0.58045132774289632     
  -11.842481592786449       -5.7083783211328551        1.9526760053685255     
  -10.240286781275808        13.204312088815593        4.4856524683466175     
  -4.6690658488407504       -6.2809313597959449        7.4378900284937082     
  -9.5874077836478282       -8.6799071183782903       -1.8203838010218165     
  0.62588896716878051       -5.4614995295716540        11.166650096421838     
           0        4173
           0        1998
           0         611
           0        8606
           1        6912
           1        9671
           1        7993
           1        8513
           2        5556
           2        4422
           2        3047
```

I cannot simply use `loadtxt()` to read such a file because this would result in the error `ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line ...`

Is there a way to use `loadtxt()` or some similar function to read such a file?

I would like to avoid using `readlines()` and `split()` and then convert to float, because this would make the code slower (I think...) and longer. I have also tried `pandas.read_csv()`, but I need an array as output.

---

**Update:**

For now, following **hpaulj**'s suggestion, I'm doing it like this using `readlines()` and `split()`:

```
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        all_data=[x.split() for x in f.readlines()]
        a=array([map(float,x) for x in all_data[:N]])
        b=array([map(int,x) for x in all_data[N+1:]])
```

It is actually pretty fast, but I would still like to know if someone knows a faster -and maybe simpler- method.

Comment: Your own read and split won't be slower. That's what the numpy fns do. Just accumulate values as. Lists of lists and make the arrays after.  Try it, and ask about the code if you aren't happy with the speed.

Comment: @hpaulj You are right, I have tried it and it is actually pretty fast.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `pandas.read_csv()` and then obtaining the numpy array using the `.values` attribute from the `DataFrame` - [see documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt")
array_values = df.values
```

Right now if you just use `.values` then you will get `nan` for the missing values. You can determine `M` and `N` by checking for indices that contain `nan` for the missing values.

Comment: Sorry, I have looked at the link but I couldn't really understand. How is that done in practice?

Comment: This doesn't give me the output I'm looking for. Looks like an array of strings.

Comment: have you tried `data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=" +", engine="python",header=None)` on your data file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the numpy function : `np.genfromtxt()`

```
import numpy as np

reading = np.genfromtxt("file", delimiter=" ")
```

Can you post an example of your .txt file ?

Comment: I included an example of my file. I have tried this method, but I obtain an array of `nan`

Comment: @valerio92 The hpaulj's answer is very good. I didn't see your data file when I answered you.

Comment: No problem, it was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Using `[x.split() for x in f.readlines()]` will unfortunately load all lines as strings objects in a python list, which will be slow and require a lot more memory than a numpy array.

Assuming you know in advance the line of the split (since you used `N` in your suggestion), you can do the following:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    first_part = numpy.loadtxt(islice(f, N))
    second_part = numpy.loadtxt(f)
```

[`islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is a tool that will stop generating lines after numpy has read `N` lines. When calling the second `loadtxt` on the same file, numpy will start where it previously stopped, so you don't have to do anything more.

Because it's using only generators, it doesn't require to store all the intermediary lines as strings.