# How to use np.genfromtxt and fill in missing columns?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use `np.genfromtxt` to load a data that looks something like this into a matrix:

```
0.79  0.10  0.91   -0.17 0.10  0.33  -0.90 0.10  -0.19 -0.00 0.10  -0.99 -0.06 0.10  -0.42 -0.66 0.10  -0.79 0.21  0.10  0.93  0.79  0.10  0.91  -0.72 0.10  0.25  0.64  0.10  -0.27 -0.36 0.10  -0.66 -0.52 0.10  0.92  -0.39 0.10  0.43  0.63  0.10  0.25  -0.58 0.10  -0.03 0.59  0.10  0.02  -0.69 0.10  0.79  0.30  0.10  0.09  0.70  0.10  0.67  -0.04 0.10  -0.65 -0.07 0.10  0.70  -0.06 0.10  0.08  7  566 112 32 163 615 424 543 424 422 490 47 499 595 94 515 163 535 
 0.79  0.10  0.91   -0.17 0.10  0.33  -0.90 0.10  -0.19 -0.00 0.10  -0.99 -0.06 0.10  -0.42 -0.66 0.10  -0.79 0.21  0.10  0.93  0.79  0.10  0.91  -0.72 0.10  0.25  0.64  0.10  -0.27 -0.36 0.10  -0.66 -0.52 0.10  0.92  -0.39 0.10  0.43  0.63  0.10  0.25  -0.58 0.10  -0.03 0.59  0.10  0.02  -0.69 0.10  0.79  0.30  0.10  0.09  0.70  0.10  0.67  -0.04 0.10  -0.65 -0.07 0.10  0.70  -0.06 0.10  0.08  263 112 32 30 163 366 543 457 424 422 556 55 355 485 112 515 163 509 112 535 
 0.79  0.10  0.91   -0.17 0.10  0.33  -0.90 0.10  -0.19 -0.00 0.10  -0.99 -0.06 0.10  -0.42 -0.66 0.10  -0.79 0.21  0.10  0.93  0.79  0.10  0.91  -0.72 0.10  0.25  0.64  0.10  -0.27 -0.36 0.10  -0.66 -0.52 0.10  0.92  -0.39 0.10  0.43  0.63  0.10  0.25  -0.58 0.10  -0.03 0.59  0.10  0.02  -0.69 0.10  0.79  0.30  0.10  0.09  0.70  0.10  0.67  -0.04 0.10  -0.65 -0.07 0.10  0.70  -0.06 0.10  0.08  311 112 32 543 457 77 639 355 412 422 509 112 535 163 77 125 30 412 422 556 55 355 485 112 515
```

Suppose I want to import data into a matrix of size (4, 5). If not all rows have 5 columns, when it imports the matrix it should replace those columns without 5 rows with "". For example, if the data were simpler, it would look like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,"","","",""
```

Thus, I want the number of columns to be imported to match that of the max row column count, and if a row doesn't have that many columns, it will fill it with "". I am reading from a file called "data.txt".

This is what I have tried so far:

```
trainData = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', usecols = range(0, 5), invalid_raise=False, missing_values = "", filling_values="")
```

However, it gives errors saying:

```
Line #4 (got 1 columns instead of 5)
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to fill in the extra delimiters, `'16, , , ,'`.  `genfromtxt` cannot do that for you.

Comment: How do I do that then?

Can I parse the file manually and add them in somehow to generate the same matrix?

Comment: With standard file read and edit methods.; `genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that can feed it lines.

Comment: What do you mean by `standard file read and edit methods`. I don't understand, should I read the file line by line and then when doing that fill in the "", and then pass list of strings that to `genfromtxt`?

Comment: Please help, I am unable to figure this out still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out a solution.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([line.strip().split() for line in open('data.txt', 'r')])
data = np.array(df)
```

Comment: This will give you an array of strings. If that't not what you want you can use `data = np.array(df.astype('float64'))`.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has more robust readers and you can use the `DataFrame` methods to handle the missing values.

You'll have to figure out how many columns to use first:

```
columns = max(len(l.split()) for l in open('data.txt'))
```

To read the file:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_table('data.txt', 
                       delim_whitespace=True, 
                       header=None, 
                       usecols=range(columns), 
                       engine='python')
```

To convert to a numpy array:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array(df)
```

This will fill in NaNs in the blank positions. You can use `.fillna()` to get other values for blanks.

```
filled = numpy.array(df.fillna(999))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I tried `df = pandas.read_csv(train_file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)` and I get an error saying `Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 81 fields in line 4, saw 91`. I don't get why it is a struggle to do this in python, in Julia I can just do `readdlm`

Comment: I tested on the data you posted. Perhaps post your actual data file and I can check how to fix it.

Comment: I think the problem is in the last part, which is integers. Is there some way to manually parse this and create a matrix of both floats and integers, where the integer part (which seems to be the part where data is missing) is filled with "" if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Using the python engine works fine as long as you know how many columns to use. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Your edit doesn't work, because the shape of the data frame is `(1719, 84)`, instead of `(11800×145)`. It seems like it has omitted columns that do not have length of 84. However, the value of columns is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution, check the answer that I posted. I upvoted you because it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the `filling_values` argument to `np.nan` (which is considered of type float so you won't have the string conversion issue) and specify the delimiter to be comma since by default `genfromtxt` expects only white space as delimiters:

```
trainData = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', usecols = range(0, 5), invalid_raise=False, missing_values = "", filling_values=np.nan, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, gives the same bug as before: `Line #1 (got 130 columns instead of 146)` and so on.

Comment: it works for the example you provided. How does your data look like? Actually using just `np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',')` works for me. What versions of numpy/python you are using?

Comment: I am using python 3. Are you sure it works on the data I posted in the top of my question? Not the one with 5 columns, but the one with 3 rows. Doesn't work for me. And this command seems to add in some random data with 'nan' in the middle of the data columns.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood your question. Try @chthonicdaemon answer again with `df = pandas.read_csv(train_file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, usecols=range(91))` and it should work, since `pandas` fills missing values with `nan` automatically. Its important to use the argument `usecols=range(91)`, so you must know # of cols. Otherwise try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201362/numpy-loadtxt-with-variable-number-of-columns)

Comment: Are you sure it should be `usecols=range(91)`? Because that gives an error: `ValueError: Usecols do not match names.`

Comment: The answer that you linked is trying to do something different, no? Their file is split up into either 2 or 3 columns, and there are M rows for one and N rows for the other. My file has each row with a different column, and I need to generate a matrix from that.

Comment: it really depends on your file format, and you need to tailor those to your needs...

Answer (score 0):

With the copy-n-paste of the 3 big lines, this pandas reader works:

```
In [149]: pd.read_csv(BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True,header=None,error_bad_
     ...: lines=False,names=list(range(91)))
Out[149]: 
     0    1     2     3    4     5    6    7     8    9   ...     81   82  \
0  0.79  0.1  0.91 -0.17  0.1  0.33 -0.9  0.1 -0.19 -0.0  ...    515  163   
1  0.79  0.1  0.91 -0.17  0.1  0.33 -0.9  0.1 -0.19 -0.0  ...    515  163   
2  0.79  0.1  0.91 -0.17  0.1  0.33 -0.9  0.1 -0.19 -0.0  ...    125   30   

    83     84     85    86     87     88     89     90  
0  535    NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
1  509  112.0  535.0   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  
2  412  422.0  556.0  55.0  355.0  485.0  112.0  515.0
```

`_.values` to get the array.

The key is specifying a big enough `names` list.  Pandas can fill incomplete lines, while `genfromtxt` requires explicit delimiters.