# How do I read the second column using genfromtxt?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

Consider the following data file:

```
! cat datax
1
1.000
2.000   3.000
3.000   4.000
5.000   6.000
```

the lines:

```
f=open('datax', 'r') 
d=np.genfromtxt(f, dtype=None, missing_values=0,usecols=(0))
f.close()
```

succeed but the lines:

```
f=open('datax', 'r') 
d=np.genfromtxt(f, dtype=None, missing_values=0,usecols=(0,1))
f.close()
```

fail. I get the error:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
   Line #1 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
   Line #2 (got 1 columns instead of 2)
```

This is because the first two data points of the second column are missing. Special treatment of this case with first missing values is not an option. How do I read the data while ignoring the missing values?

Comment: See [this for possible help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481997/how-to-use-np-genfromtxt-and-fill-in-missing-columns).  Basically, `pandas` can handle this more easily than `numpy`...

Comment: What do you mean by 'ignoring the missing values'?  Skipping those rows entirely, or filling the missing values with some sort of `nan`?

Comment: @hpa filling with missing values